# Filtering rows from a dataframe and create a new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I append information created by changing parameter in the function?
For example, I have

```
def function_test(par):
    f=too[too["body"].str.contains(par), 'clothes']
    return(f)
```

where

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"body": ["ball", "red BALL", "round sphere"], "clothes": ["shorts", "pants", "shirt"]})
```

Let's say I am interested in `ball` and `round sphere`; this means I would use the function twice:

```
function_test('ball')
function_test('round sphere')
```

How can I generate a list/new dataset with only the rows filtered by using the function above, still keeping all the columns from my original dataset (i.e. `body` and `clothes`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
search_li = ['ball', 'round sphere']
df[df['body'].str.contains('|'.join(search_li))]
```

---

```
    body            clothes
0   ball            shorts
2   round sphere    shirt
```

---

**Edit:**

```
def function_test(par):
    f = df[df["body"].str.contains(par)]
    return(f)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
new_df = new_df.append(function_test('ball'))
new_df = new_df.append(function_test('round sphere'))
```

---

**new_df:**

```
    body            clothes
0   ball            shorts
2   round sphere    shirt
```

Comment: Hi @Pygirl, I would need to keep the function, if possible, as I need to see with clothes are associated to body. Probably it would be better to create elements separately, for example w1=function_test('ball'), w2=function_test('round sphere') then create a dataframe. I can append them, but I do not know how to create a dataframe with them

Comment: Check my edited answer. This will reset the index: `new_df = new_df.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)`